# jQuery Chosen does not work with 2 forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen

I have two forms. Second one is just the same the first one, only difference is the names and IDs input fields and select boxes. For example in the first one has an input field like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" placeholder="First name">
```

...and the second one has an input filed like this:

```
<input type="text" name="fname2" id="fname2" placeholder="First name">
```

Nothing else.

In the first one form it's working fine, but it isn't working in the second one. Just show a little box without any text.

No error messages, nothing in the console log.

Any idea?

Comment: You didn't tell us, how are you submitting the form?

Comment: please share your js code

Answer (score 0):

try by initializing both control separate by id like below

```
$("#chosen1").chosen();
$("#chosen2").chosen();
```

bcoz i think your second form chosen control is not initialized.